# Is it possible to detect if my app is running and displaying on screen?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to detect if my app is running and displaying on screen?
As we know, ios is supporting multi-task.
But I prefer to get the status if my app is running in front of all app and interact to users.

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This flowchart will clarify how the management of the multitasking works in iOS 4.0+:
[image]

(taken from [here](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/))

What you need to do is just to manage a variable set by the various messages sent to your delegate, eg `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidEnterBackground`, in this way you can easily understand in which state is the application and behave accordingly.