# Is it possible to detect if iphone/ipo/ipad is activating(user is using them)

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to detect if my app is running and displaying on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088734/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-my-app-is-running-and-displaying-on-screen)

Hello everyone

My app is running in background.
Is it possible to detect if iphone/ipo/ipad is activating(user is using them) rath than is sleeping or locked screen ?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not when it's in the background. You only receive messages from the OS when your application is involved in the event.