# How to handle phone call interrupts in iPhones below iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios

In one of my application I need to handle call interrupt. I know application will directly enter background in iOS 4 onwards. How can I handle this situation devices with iOS's less than 4. Do I need to implement any delegate method to be get notified that a call interrupt has come. Please help.

Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: I already answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088734/is-it-possible-to-detect-if-my-app-is-running-and-displaying-on-screen/6088776#6088776

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below Appdelegate method:

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

  This delegate will call when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.

To Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface. For this use the below appDelegate

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Is this delegate available from iOS 3 onwards?. Or only available since iOS 4. If Not available, how can I do it devices running on iOS 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [The Application Life Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW17). You will find there the difference between iOS 4.0 and earlier versions.